# Calcular o tempo decorrido após criação de um registro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gostaria de saber como **calcular o tempo entre a criação de um registro (created_at) e o horário atual**. Meu intuito é exibir essa diferença em segundos, minutos, horas ou dias que isso ocorreu.
Existe algum **método/gem** para realizar essa tarefa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi a questão utilizando o seguinte método [`time_ago_in_words`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words)

Em sua view utilize o código:

```
há <%= time_ago_in_words(notification.created_at) %>
```

Caso sua data passada como parâmetro no método seja `19:00 13/12/2017` e o horário atual seja `19:07 13/12/2017`, o resultado será: `há 07 minutos`. Funciona também quando a diferença é para segundos, horas e dias.